# Performance parsing JSON on Android emulator vs physical device

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-emulator

I'm developing an app wich needs to parse at least 20.000 objetcs from JSON to POJOs so I'm testing JSON parsing times according device's hardware.

Because that, I thought to use an emulator to test differents specs. The thing is, using Genymotion or Andy or another emulator, parsing times are extremely low compared to parsing time on a physical device with the same specs.

For example:

HoneyWell E70 (1 core @1Ghz / 512 Mb RAM): 2 minutes.

Custom emulator phone (1 core @1Ghz / 512 Mb RAM): 18 seconds.

Parsing on emulator gives you "unreal" performance times? Or emulator times are "real" and it's just that HoneyWell's CPU really sucks parsing?

I don't know wich one is the normal parsing time and, for the moment, I don't have a third device to compare HoneyWell and emulator against it.

Comment: emulators are much slower than real devices. You should always test performance times with real devices as this will give you more accurate numbers.

Comment: In this case is the opposite, emulators are quite fast than real device, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was option 2: HoneyWell's CPU really sucks parsing. I could find a third device to compare and emulator was correct.